# Double import of jQuery causes error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery-ui

I am reloading a part of my page every 5 seconds with Javascript. This works fine!
However, if I add a parameter I am getting the same page without reloading.

If I open it without reloading, I am seeing the jQuery UI progress bars correctly.
If I open the reloading page, they are not shown anymore - although the script get's the unreloading site and write it into the div, so you should see them.

I am afraid this happens because they stylesheets or the jquery part is loosing his old values or is overwritten.

This is the reloading page: http://lasertra.de/table.php
This is how it should be, unreloading page: http://lasertra.de/table.php?refresh=true

Also if I am not reloading the jQuery scripts it doesn't show up correctly, if they scripts are not added in the not reloading page, it doesn't show the progress bars too, so it seems like it is needed.

I am not reloading the whole page, only the signals div which is placed in the body

```
function update_table()
{
    var old_id = document.getElementById('number').value;

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(req.readyState == 4)
    {
        if(req.status == 200)
        {
            var new_table = req.responseText;

            var new_id = document.getElementById('number').value;
            if(new_id != old_id)
            {
                var someSound = soundManager.createSound({ 
                url: 'signal.mp3'
                });
                someSound.play();
            }
            document.getElementById("signals").innerHTML = new_table;
            setTimeout(update_table, 1000);
        }
        }
    }
    var link = "table.php?refresh=true";  
    req.open("GET", link, false);
    req.send();

}
```

Comment: You should really consider not loading the entire page again, just the parts that needs to be updated. Like the table as a json-string or something. I am not 100% sure why this is happening, but is looks like  the js-code in the new DOM is never executed.

Comment: Can we see the code that you're using to reload without having to trawl through source?

Comment: "However, if I add a parameter I am getting the same page without reloading." **Add a parameter where?**

Comment: @popnoodles : js-file is in http://lasertra.de/signals.js and by parameter I am guessing the get-parameter?

Comment: Code has been added :)

Comment: I thought that too @OptimusCrime but I don't like to guess

Comment: After discussion the problem is apparent by the grey bars disappear on one of the URLs given. I've deleted my answer so that other devs will see this is unanswered.